# channel related videos only (rel=0) in embedded code from YouTube OEmbed API

Tags: youtube-api

I'm using YouTube OEmbed API.
I use it by sending it a url like: https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytbsekLVdAI and it responds with a JSON that contains the iframe embed HTML code as one of the JSON properties.

I would like for it to add the "rel=0" parameter in its iframe src url, so that once the video ends - it shows related videos from only the video's channel.

so I tried appending the url I'm sending in with "rel=0" like this: https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytbsekLVdAI&rel=0
but that didn't work as it ignored the "rel=0" and returned the same iframe embed code.

looks though the API documentations and found nothing related.

now I know I can just modify the "src" in the embedded code I got in the response JSON but isn't there a more elegant way to achieve what I want? something I can send/modify in the request to the youtube oembed api?